# In Java Spring, save an entity with his related 1 to 1 association

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am learning Java Spring and JPA Persistance.

I try to save an entity that has another one as 1 to 1 relation. My plan is: First I save the `user` and, once it is created, I add it to `setting`.

```java
var enduser = endUserRepo.save(new User("User1"));
settingRepo.save(new Setting(enduser));
```

BUT I get the following error: `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.oman.user.User`

`user` is saved in DB properly, but not the `setting`:

For context, the relation defined between entities:

```java
@Entity
public class Setting {

    // more code 

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @NonNull
    private User user;
```

```java
@Entity
public class User {

   // more code

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Setting setting;
}
```

What is wrong? I can provide more code if needed but I think it is a beginner error and anyone with experience will point in the right direction.

Comment: The error is likely because the call you are making isn't within the same transactional context. If you wrap the two save calls in a single transaction, what is returned from the first save will be managed (ie not detached) and so can be used in the second save call - and both will be inserted or rolled back together.  Otherwise, if you must use two transactions, this is an issue with the save logic - it will call em.persist on your new entity when what you might want here is em.merge called instead. Or you can remove the cascade persist/merge options on the setting->user relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment:

The error occurs because the first save for a new User is being handled in a separate transactional context. When that transaction is committed, which occurs before it returns, all entities become detached - it just means they exist in the database but are not tracked by JPA, so their state is really unknown after. There are quite a few rules on managed/detached entities in JPA so that providers can be consistent on all the data they are required to manage and the state is handled consistently between them.

Specifically here, you've got a cascade persist operation set on the Setting->User mapping. This forces JPA, when persisting a setting to also call persist on the referenced User. Persist is similar to requesting an insert, and since it already exists, it is expected to throw an exception. This can be confusing since persist calls on already managed entities are no-ops and just ignored.

So when creating a new entity, the best practice is to read in existing references (your user instance) using the same EntityManager context that you are going to use to persist the new entity, ensuring that there will not be any references to detached entities. The cascade settings on the mappings then do not matter, and there is no (or just less) risk of accidentally overwriting an existing User instance with stale data, or re-inserting a deleted row.

In this case, that would just mean wrapping both save calls in the same transaction.

That isn't always possible, and you may not want to force the second save operation to have to read in the User entity just so JPA can re-load or manage a user Instance. Some badly explained demos just have things work by automatically setting the cascade merge operation, and then merge in the Setting instead of calling persist on it - this would take your new Setting instance and have JPA detect if needs an insert or update statement. This then will cascade that merge operation to the User - usually reading in the User instance so that it can also tell if it should be an insert or update operation. Draw back, in addition to JPA having read detached entities from the database to determine what changed, is that if there are changes to the user from concurrent operations, or you just have a very stale or incomplete User instance associated, JPA will take the instance you've given it and use those property values to overwrite what is currently in the database. Don't use cascade persist/merge lightly. If that is the behavior you want, Spring's save implementation isn't correct anyway; it does its own determination to see if the entity passed in is new, and will call persist - which JPA will cascade to the User instance if the mapping is set to. If Spring doesn't detect it is new, it'll call em.merge - which is what you might really want, and this Spring logic confuses new users too as it is (IMO) poorly explained.

Options here might either to be:

1. Wrap both calls in the same transaction
2. Remove the cascade persist setting on the Setting->User mapping
3. Use entityManager.merge(setting) instead of Spring save logic.

#3 might require writing your own repository save method. It might be worth doing except that Option 1 and 2 will be better performance wise anyway if you didn't mean to have this second transaction pick up changes to the User since it was last synchronized to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really creating a relationship between the user and the setting.

You need to do something like this:

```
Setting setting = new Setting();
User user = new User();
setting.setUser(user);
settingRepo.save(setting);
```

This should save both Setting and User and create a relationship between them.

Comment: HI @Tobb thanks for your answer, it does not work `ERROR: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint` because `user` instance does not have `id` generated.

Comment: You should avoid not null constraints on foreign keys when using Hibernate, as it might do things in multiple steps. So here it could be that it first inserts to the two tables, and then fixes the foregin with an update. So try to remove the not null from your column.

Comment: Having a not-null constraint is not normally an issue in foreign keys - The only place I know it to have issues is with unidirectional OneToMany relationships (where you specify the join column on the OneToMany Mapping), as the row with the FK value doesn't know about the FK, so they can be inserted and updated independently. Otherwise, unless you've got multiple nodes pointing at each other all with not-null FK constraints (A problem for your app), this shouldn't be an issue.